# Generating a list of consecutive numbers as strings

Tags: python, list

I would like to generate a list of numbers such as this:

```
['1','2','3','4','5','6']
```

but all I can seem to get is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

using this code:

```
values = list(range(1,7))
```

Is there some easy way to generate a list of consecutive numbers, that are within apostrophes, since I want the code to treat them like a string.

I have tried:

```
values = str(list(range(1,7)))
```

but that just gave me the same result as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> [str(i) for i in range(1,7)]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

`list(map(str, range(1,7)))`

Answer (score 1):

The comprehension proposed by @CoryKramer has you covered, but given your attempts, you might be looking for:

```
>>> list(map(str, range(1, 7)))
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```